# Is there an API for querying the size of a Wikipedia article, given its title?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, imdb

I'm writing a browser extension that attaches the wikipedia article length next to movie titles on lists from imdb.com. Hopefully, longer articles indicate better movies. Getting the length in words would be ideal, but so far I can't get anything out of their REST API at https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/.

This paper from 2008 on the subject used a full wikipedia dump and processed the article text: http://www.jblumenstock.com/files/papers/jblumenstock_www08.pdf. But I'm hoping there is an API for this that could be called from a browser extension.

Once I figure this out, the next hurdle will be to get a wikipedia link given the title and year (or imdb link) for a movie.

EDIT: here is the working extension: https://github.com/harjoc/imdb-wiki-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another API to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Testing with the movie *Appiness* you can use the `action=query` asking for the `prop=info` like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Appiness&format=json

Which will give you, among some other metadata `"length": 3675` which is the length in bytes.